# Upper bound for semilinear heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary. Let $u \in C^{2,1}(\bar{\Omega} \times [0,\infty)) $ be a solution to
$$
u_t=\Delta u-u^3 \; \;                         (x,t) \in \Omega \times [0,\infty) \\
u(x,t)=0   \; \;                         (x,t) \in \partial \Omega \times [0,\infty)
$$
I wish to show that $\int_{\Omega}u^2(x,1)dx \leq |\Omega |$. My attempt:
Consider
$$
h(t)=\frac{1}{|\Omega |}\int_{\Omega}u^2(x,t)dx
$$
Then we have
$$
(\frac{1}{h(t)})'=\frac{-1}{h^2(t)}\frac{1}{|\Omega |}\int_{\Omega}\partial_tu^2(x,t)dx= \\
-\frac{1}{h^2(t)}\frac{2}{|\Omega |}\int_{\Omega}\partial_tu(x,t)u(x,t)dx= \\
-\frac{1}{h^2(t)}\frac{2}{|\Omega |}\int_{\Omega}(\Delta u-u^3)udx= \\
-\frac{1}{h^2(t)}\frac{2}{|\Omega |}\int_{\Omega}-|\nabla u|^2-u^4dx=\\
\frac{1}{h^2(t)}\frac{2}{|\Omega |}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2+u^4dx 
$$
But I can not continue here - how do I show that
$$
h(1) \leq 1
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{h(1)} \geq 1
$$
Ive tried solving this ODE explicitly, but I got confused. Also I suspect a Gronwall-argument, but can not figure it out.

Comment: what's the initial condition?

Comment: You can chose any. The initial condition on the heat equation also determines the one of $h$ i.e. $h(0)=\frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int_{\Omega}u(x,0)dx=\frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int_{\Omega}f(x)dx=c$ for some function $f$, which is the inital condition for the heat equation.